# Placing Circles instead of Markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to add 2 circles(red and green) instead of the default marker on the google maps. I need the color of the circles to change(increase/decrease of intensity) based on the values in the database. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This question is way too open. What exactly are you doing? What technologies are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: kind of like this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple except you would be altering the fillColor and fillOpacity instead of the radius

Comment: I am using JavaScript. I want to remove the default marker that appears and have 2 circles in its place (something like traffic lights). I have tried using overlays. But it doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: What you want is just a circular marker : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a circle as a marker icon, for example:

```
var oMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    sName: "Marker Name",
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8.5,
        fillColor: "#F00",
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 0.4
    },
});
```

and then, if you want to change the marker dynamically (like on mouseover), you can, for example:

```
oMarker.setIcon({
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10,
            fillColor: "#0F0",
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1
        })
```

Comment: why make a circle-as-a-marker-icon when you can just make a circle (see examples posted by me and Tao P.R in the comments to OP)?

Comment: @lucas You already covered how to make a circle.  Now here is how to make a circle marker.  Because that may be useful in some use case.  It has been for me.

Comment: I guess that's what got me curious - what would that use case be?

Comment: My Markers changed.  This way its easy to create an animation for it to turn into a square for example.  Or a custom icon.